# Change keyboard input on Xamarin android player

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-android-player

For Xamarin development I'm using the new/preview Android player. Now I have an issue when typing from my physical keyboard (danish). I'm not able to use the danisk layout in the player and would really like to as it is kind of a pain to mouse click the mobile keyboard in the android player.
I tried changing some of the input settings, but no luck so far. Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Which device are you using in Xamarin Android Player?

Comment: I have a physical keyboard with a DK-danish layout. works fine in IOS simulator but not the android player.

Comment: Oh device, nexus 4 and nexus 7